# is there a data structure with O(1) insertion time which also maintains sorted order?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, hashtable

hash tables can insert in O(1), but they aren't sorted.

BSTs maintain an ordering (can be traversed using pre-order traversal) but insertion is O(logN).

is there any data structure that:

1. guarantees O(1) insertion
2. maintains an ordering over the elements?

if not, is there a proof that such a data structure cannot exist?
thanks

Comment: @ggorlen Python dictionaries don't maintain "sorted" order, they maintain insertion order. That is rather different. If you just want O(1) insertion while maintaining insertion order, that would be trivial; standard list data structures do that, with `append` or `push` to insert a value at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, such a data structure is impossible because you could use it to sort a sequence with O(n) comparison operations, simply by inserting the sequence elements into it one-by-one. It is straightforward to show that Ω(n log n) is a lower bound for the [number of comparisons required to sort a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), so insertion into a data structure which "maintains sorted order" must take at least Ω(log n) time per element.

Here I am assuming that it is possible to iterate over the data structure in order to output a sorted list, without doing any additional comparisons. If additional comparisons are required simply to iterate over the data structure's contents, then it is fair to say the data structure doesn't "maintain" sorted order internally. If you don't mind it taking O(n log n) time to iterate over a collection of size n, then you could just use an unsorted list as your data structure, with O(1) insertion time.

Answer (score 1):

You can trade more space for this **O(1)**. If the value domain is integral, say from 0 to N-1,
then you could have a

```
// (In Java)
int[] valueToFrequency = new int[N];

void insert(int value) {
    ++valueToFrequency[value];
}
```

For N values: **O(N)**.

The difficulty (besides the value mapping, and 0 based indexing) is that the array is sparse: many zeroes.
Hence the output is slow.

For unique values (as "hashtable" suggests), one can use BitSet in Java. This is also a bit faster on output (nextSetBit).

```
// (In Java)
BitSet valueToFrequency = new Bitset(N);

void insert(int value) {
    valueToFrequency.set(value);
}
```

Comment: ah, i see. so this gets around the nlogn lower bound on comparison based sorting by using a concept similar to radix sort? presumably, you would also need a way to convert all your elements into ints?

Comment: Above the value domain is 0..(N-1), and using the value as index, one gets a huge sorted sparse array, BitSet being the best representation. One could translate a domain -A..+B to 0..(A+B). It is not a very elegant solution. Radix sort is O(N) or O(N.w) where w is the number of digits, which is log(N). So though radix sort is said to be linear - O(N), I personally consider it not much different from other sorts with O(N.log N). The above has O(N): N times inserting a value with O(1). The drawback is with the output.